# react-router Cannot GET /route

Tags: ecmascript-6, react-router, react-redux, webpack-dev-server, jsx

Ok, guys, here's the problem... I've been writing code for my web application using another fluently working app as an example for the beginning. Here is the source code:

(./app.jsx)

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
    import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
    import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

    import App from './components/app';
    import Signin from './components/auth/signin';
    import reducers from './reducers';

    const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware()(createStore);

    ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
          <Route path='/' component={App}>
            <Route path='signin' component={Signin} />
          </Route>
        </Router>
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById('app')
    );
```

(./components/app.js)

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import Header from './header';

    export default class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Header />
            {this.props.children}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

(./components/auth/signing.js)

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

    class Signin extends Component {
      handleFormSubmit({ email, password }) {
        console.log(email, password);
      }

      render() {
        const { handleSubmit, fields: { email, password }} = this.props;

        return (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
            <fieldset className="form-group">
              <label>Email</label>
              <input {...email} className="form-control"/ >
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset className="form-group">
              <label>Email</label>
              <input {...password} className="form-control"/ >
            </fieldset>
            <button action="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
          </form>
        );
      }
    }

    export default reduxForm({
      form: 'signin',
      fields: ['email', 'password']
    })(Signin);
```

(you can see my whole repository here: https://github.com/LiJuons/react-dribbble )

The thing is that when I go to localhost:3000 - everything's Ok, but when I enter localhost:3000/signin - I get error message that says "Cannot GET /signin" THOUGH the application I'm taking code from works properly and shows form!
The problem is in routes, because if I set signin.js route's path to '/' in my project, form is shown on home directory without any problem.

Package.json files are the same in both projects (same number of packages, same versions and dependencies), only start script differs, so...

THE ONLY DIFFERENCE between the working project and mine is that in working one 'npm start' script is defined as:

```
    "start": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js"
```

where in mine it's:

```
    "start": "node server.js"
```

P.S. I checked every line to be sure that code of both projects would be as homogeneous as possible.

Any suggestions how to fix this issue?
Thank you

Comment: What version of redux form are you using? If its the newer version, your export statement needs to change, I can get you some code for that, if you tell me what version of redux form is in your package.json file.

Comment: @DanielZuzevich     "redux-form": "^3.1.7" You can see my whole package list on https://github.com/LiJuons/react-dribbble/blob/master/package.json

Comment: Have you tried changing the npm start command back to the one that is in the other persons project? Also, was the /signin route added by you personally, or was it already in the project you took the source code from. I think you are having a compile error, where your bundle.js file is not being updated to have the signin route inside of it. All of the JS code in your app is compiled into bundle.js, I don't think its updated to have that route.

Comment: @DanielZuzevich I wrote everything myself in this one. If I change script to 'node... webpack-dev-server.js' my app crashes saying it can't find modules or smtg (I made this app from scratch, chose that 'node server.js' start script so I could easily deploy this app on heroku). Everything else seems to work fine, only routes are broken ('children' routes to be precise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server is probably not configured to support HTML5 history.

Take a look at https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-react-deployment-5a717d4378fd

**React-router not working when typing URL manually**

This is a common surprise and is related to the fact that you are using browserHistory in your application, which requires some additional configuration of the server itself. Basically, when you type the URL by hand, by default the server will look for a file with that path, stored on its disk — if not found, it will show a 404 error. What you want to do is internally redirect the request to the index of your application.

You can see the documentation for react-router v3 about this setting (don’t worry, it’s still valid for react-router 4!). Common configuration are:

express:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080
const app = express()
// this assumes that all your app files
// `public` directory relative to where your server.js is
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

app.get('*', function (request, response){
  response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
})

app.listen(port)
console.log("Server started on port " + port);
```

Comment: That's the case! It works now, appreciate your help! Thank You!

Comment: Also the URL's in index.html should be absolute, what I mean is:
bad: `<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>`
good:  <script type="text/javascript" src="/bundle.js"></script>`

In the bad example if enter the URL: www.example/path/value and get back the index.html, the browser will fetch bundle.js file at www.example/path/bundle.js. This was problematic for me.